# How to override a readonly property in superclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, properties

I have a property defined in superclass.h as so:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSArray *objects;
```

I have no access to the .m file.

In my subclass there are some cases where I need to write to this `objects` property.

I've tried the following two solutions:

1. Declare an overriding `readwrite` property called `objects` in my subclass. However, this gives me an error when [super viewDidLoad] is called about the `setObjects` setter in the superclass.
2. Declare a different property in my subclass - `commentObjects` - and include a flag to use either the superclass' `objects` array property or this subclass property. There are times when it's fine to use the objects the superclass loads but others where I need to use the one my subclass loads. This does work, however is very messy and just seems like bad design using two differently named properties for the same data.

Is there a way to do this by just using one property?

Comment: have you tried using Categories ? 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand upon your second approach a little: rather than including a `BOOL` flag to indicate what property to use, override the getter of your property to return either the value of the `objects` from the superclass, or the value of your own settable `commentObjects` property:

```
-(NSArray*)objects {
    return usecCmmentObjects ? commentObjects : [super objects];
}
```

Comment: I ended up using a version of this.